# How to delete scheduled tasks

Tags: windows, tasks

my friend were over and though it would be funny to create scheduled task on my windows 10 that pop us a message every 10 minutes

They created the following bat file to delete it but it doesn't work:

```
@echo off
schtasks /End /TN "hello" /F
schtasks /Delete /TN "hello" /F
```

Now they don't know how to fix it cause the bat file above doesn't stop the message. I tried restarting but it doesn't help.

Is there a way to delete all user created scheduled tasks permanently? It annoys me that I can't play a game or watch a movie quietly without being alt-tabbed out of it cause of the message.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Nice friend LOL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, don't know how this scheduled task in question is done/created, but the regular way to handle these in Windows is -> Control Panel -> "Monitoring Tools" -> Scheduled Tasks -> Microsoft -> Windows -> "some task" , and there deleting it ...

Answer (score 0):

In first answer is stupid windows-way. I tired deleting ALL tasks... Create reg file with

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree\Microsoft\Windows\SOMETaskDIR]
```